# gettag() is getting only last index value of an array

Tags: android, arrays, tags

I am getting values from web services and filling it `textviews` and I am also setting tags on some values because I have to send those values on other activity on a button click. but I am only getting the last value of an array.

```
txt_TransStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    TextView cr = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_StatusValue);
    TextView pid = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_DateValue);
    TextView amount = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_RechargeAmountValue);
    TextView phone = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_PhoneValue);
    TextView pin = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_PinNumberValue);

    Intent intent = new Intent(con, GetTransData.class);
    intent.putExtra("CRID", cr.getTag().toString());
    intent.putExtra("PID", pid.getTag().toString());
    intent.putExtra("Amount", amount.getTag().toString());
    intent.putExtra("Phone", phone.getTag().toString());
    intent.putExtra("PINNum", pin.getTag().toString());
    con.startActivity(intent);    
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my code with this:

OnClick method, changed my code to

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)v;
ProductURL = (String) iv.getTag();
```